# Parsing JSON in a listview using volley

Tags: java, android, .net

i am facing problem while parsing JSON data

here is my JSON

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 51,
        "created By": "root",
        "modified By": "root@gmail.com",
        "created Date time": null,
        "modified Date time": 1568881617000,
        "org Id": 0,
        "org Name": null,
        "name": "name",
        "address": "address",
        "state": "state",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "phone No": "1727469762",
        "value": "Value",
        "key": "51",
        "group Filter": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

can you please help me in getting it in list view with the help of volley and
the list adapter and layout inflater.

Comment: `i am facing problem` which problem?

Comment: can you get response from volley in android ?

Comment: Add the code till now you have done

Comment: @PriyaVasoya yes i get the response on the console

Comment: but i have to show it in the list view

Comment: can you share your code  which is done by you ?